# Best practices to keep Monero wallet secure

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, security, cold-storage, best-practices

I'm using a read-only wallet on a computer connected to the Internet, a dedicated local server for the **Monero** node and I keep on a USB key the full wallet as cold storage to use it only in case. Also, I have printed the seed and I'm keeping it in a safe place.

*What are the best practices to keep keys and seed secure?*

Maybe, use GPG or a dedicated software to encrypt the keys and the seed, making multiple backup copies of the USB key, make an encrypted backup and save it in cloud services, other?

*Is there a vademecum or some references for this? Where can I found it?*

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my paranoid guide for keeping your wallet safe & secure:

> I have printed the seed

That might already have screwed you up depending on how your printer was connected to your PC. Writing down the seed is the preferred way imo; make sure to use a solid desk pad to avoid imprinting / engraving what you write to other materials below your paper wallet :) In addition to that you can create a steel "wallet" containing your seed, see https://cryptosteel.com/

> I'm using a read-only wallet on a computer connected to the Internet

That means this computer holds your private view key making it possible for hackers to see the amounts you're sending and receiving. Not too unlikely given that the computer is connected to the Internet. May I ask what the reason for this Internet-connected computer is? Why does it need to have view access to your wallet?

> I keep on a USB key the full wallet as cold storage

It might be worth creating an encrypted container on the USB stick, e.g. with TrueCrypt 7.1a or [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/). In addition to that, you can encrypt the wallet with GPG to have another fence in case TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt was backdoored. Make sure to only use these tools from a computer which will never be connected to networks, e.g. the Internet. Also you should have multiple backups of that USB stick at different places, preferably in different countries in a fire and water proof safe.

> a dedicated local server for the Monero node

Just to be sure this node (even if it's downloading the blockchain **only**) should [do so through Tor via torsocks](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor).

When creating your wallet, make sure to use a computer which will never be connected to any networks. Remove its harddrive and WiFi antenna. Make sure to use a good random number generator, how to ensure that? I don't know. Use an open source OS, e.g. Debian or Tails. Only download software from trustworthy sources and verify its integrity.

I recommend to split your balance across *multiple* wallets; even if you somehow lose access to one (maybe due to hackers, robbers, etc.) you have still access to your other funds.

Comment: > May I ask what the reason for this Internet-connected computer is?

> Why does it need to have view access to your wallet?



To check incoming transactions and balance. Is it really a security issue using a read-only wallet on PC connected to the Internet? Hackers could see the amounts of sending and receiving operations, but nothing more, right?

Comment: Depending on your threat model, it might be a security issue. I for example wouldn't connect a computer storing private wallet keys to any kind of network. Hackers could only see your transaction's amounts (incoming and outgoing); so you're correct. They will not see the recipient address. Bear in mind that they will also know your address, meaning once you publish it somewhere on the web, they can associate that with you.